# Problema con hilos en c++

Tags: c++, hilos

Estoy aprendiendo de hilos en C++, este es mi codigo, es muy simple, la función `main` imprime un texto, se llama al hilo y en teoría debería de imprimirse un texto distinto en unos segundos, pero tengo un error al compilarlo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>  
using namespace std;
void saludar(void);
int main(){
    thread hilo (saludar);
    hilo.join(); 
    int i = 0;
    for(i;i<5;i++){
        cout<<"Hola, soy la funcion main.\n";
        Sleep(2000);
    }
    return 0;
}
void saludar(void){
    Sleep(5000);
    cout<<"Hola, soy la funcion saludar.\n";
    return;
}
```

Este es el error:

```
1.cpp: En la función 'int main()':
1.cpp:7:2: error: 'thread' no se declaró en este ámbito
  thread hilo (saludar);
  ^~~~~~
1.cpp:8:2: error: 'hilo' no se declaró en este ámbito
  hilo.join();
  ^~~~
```

Answer (score 2):

Las pruebas que he hecho no han dado ningún error. Creo que tu problema puede venir de una interferencia entre las utilidades de hilos incluidas a través de `<windows.h>` y las incluidas a través de `<thread>`.

No mezcles utilidades de hilos. La función [`Sleep`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) pertenece a las utilidades de `<windows.h>` mientras que estás (presuntamente) usando los hilos nativos del lenguaje proveídos por `<thread>`. Substituye esa función por [`this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for). Con esos cambios tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>  
#include <chrono>

void saludar() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
    std::cout << "Hola, soy la funcion saludar.\n";
}

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    thread hilo (saludar);
    hilo.join(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        cout<<"Hola, soy la funcion main.\n";
        this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

<sup>Puedes verlo funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0K0u6I5B003R9Ml8).</sup>

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Hay otros detalles de tu código que vale la pena mencionar:

1. En C++ las funciones que no reciben parámetros, pueden declararse y definirse con la lista vacía, no es necesario escribir `void`.

   ```
   void saludar(void); // Innecesario.
   ```

   ```
   void saludar();     // Correcto.
   ```
2. Si nada más crear un hilo llamas a [`thread::join`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join), aunque la llamada (presuntamente) se haga en otro hilo haces que la llamada sea secuencial, pues unes (join) el hilo externo al hilo principal, prueba usar [`thread::detach`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach).
3. No tiene sentido pre-declarar las variables de indizado de `for` fuera del mismo e inicializarlas dentro. Hazlo todo en el mismo.

   ```
   int i = 0;     // Esto es innecesario..
   for(i;i<5;i++) // ... e incómodo.
   ```

   ```
   for (int i=0;i<5;i++) // Mejor.
   ```
4. Deja respiara a tu código. En los 80 teníamos pantallas de 80 caracteres de ancho y 25 líneas de alto, por entonces era necesario apretujar el código para que cupiera la mayor cantidad posible en pantalla. Por suerte, esos días quedaron atrás y no es necesario redactar código como si presionar la barra espaciadora costase dinero, tus compañeros y tu yo futuro te lo agradecerán.

   ```
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++){ // Incómodo de leer.
       cout<<"Hola, soy la funcion main.\n";
   ```

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // Mejor.
       cout << "Hola, soy la funcion main.\n";
   ```
5. Favorece el [pre-incremento frente al post-incremento](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/).

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // Bien.
   ```

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) // Mejor.
   ```
6. No tiene sentido llamar a `return` al final de una función que se iba a acabar igualmente.

   ```
   void saludar(void){
   ...
   ...
       return; // ¿Por qué?
   }
   ```

   ```
   void saludar(void){
   ...
   ...
   } // Mejor.
   ```

Comment: Aún así no funciona, pero gracias por las recomendaciones.
Al compilar me me sale un error que dice que "this_thread" no está declarado. (copie y pegué el codigo para ver si funcionaba)

Comment: Prueba NO incluir `<windows.h>`, averigua también que versión de compilador estás usando, necesitarás C++11 o superior.

Comment: no estoy incluyendo windows.h, posiblemente el problema está en el compilador